# Merging MainContext blocks UI

Tags: ios, core-data, merge

I am working with Core Data and learning how things are done.  I am currently reading all data from the main context and saving all data on the background context.  I registered for notifications for when the background context is saved.  When I merge the saved changes that were on the private context, the ui stops for split second.  Is there any way to prevent that little glitch?

Here is what my context saved looks like:

```
@synchronized(self) {
    [self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        [self.mainManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ModelDidUpdateNotification
                                                            object:self.mainManagedObjectContext
                                                          userInfo:[notification userInfo]];
    }];
}
```

I've tried taking out multiple lines of code, and the glitch stops when I take out the merge.  But if I take that out.  I don't get the changes I need on the main context.

Here is the background context save:

```
[self.backgroundMainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^
 {
     saveBlock(self.backgroundMainManagedObjectContext);

     if([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread])
     {
         NSLog(@"Saving on main thread!!");
     }

     if([self.backgroundMainManagedObjectContext hasChanges])
     {
         [self.backgroundMainManagedObjectContext save:&error];
     }
 }];
```

I don't really know what I'm doing as far as Core Data is concerned.  So any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried doing everything on the main thread? You know that the background context will not write to the store if it is a child context of the main context until the main context is saved.

Comment: My background context is not a child of main context.  They just share the same persistent store.  I'll try to do everything on the main thread though.  I'll also try making the bg context a child context as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for not answering directly, I would prepare my code a little differently, so I'll write more tomorrow (it's late). In meantime if you can get access to this book, read chapter 5 Threading, and in particular 5.5 Parent-Child NSManagedObjectContext Instances. From The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra".